# Connect to Ms Access placed in the server via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have issue about how to connect to Ms access placed in the server via vb.net.. is it possible ? this is my code source im trying to create a simple program which display the data from ms access in the server

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub GetData()
        Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://159.253.148.200; Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=`Server.MapPath(/home/jaweb/public_html/MsData/data.accdb);"
        cn.Open()

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM data", cn)
        da.Fill(dt)

        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.GetData()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hold your mouse over the microsoft tag

Comment: you can use network-based access files no problem, but I rather doubt you could access them via http. maybe if webdav was in use, but not plain http.

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: i wanna know if this instead of connection to server  is correct ? cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://159.253.148.200; Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=`Server.MapPath(/home/jaweb/public_html/MsData/data.accdb);"
        cn.Open()

Comment: the error is " Internet Server Error: Object / Module not found."

Answer (score 0):

Access database over HTTP. You must setup RDS on the server for his to work.

```
Provider=MS Remote;Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Remote Server=http://server.adress.com;Data Source=d:\myPath\myDatabase.mdf;
```

[Reference: ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)